# SQL: FIter rows with specyfic pattern

Tags: sql, mariadb

I'm a bit new in sql.

I have the following table:

```
+-----+---------+------------------------+
| ID  | ID_TEST | FILE_PATH              |
+-----+---------+------------------------+
| 575 |       3 | Landscapes_001_h_A.jpg |
| 576 |       3 | Landscapes_001_h_B.jpg |
| 577 |       3 | Landscapes_001_h_C.jpg |
| 578 |       3 | Landscapes_001_h_D.jpg |
| 579 |       3 | Landscapes_001_h_E.jpg |
| 580 |       3 | Landscapes_002_h_A.jpg |
| 581 |       3 | Landscapes_002_h_B.jpg |
| 582 |       3 | Landscapes_002_h_C.jpg |
| 583 |       3 | Landscapes_002_h_D.jpg |
| 584 |       3 | Landscapes_002_h_E.jpg |
+-----+---------+------------------------+
```

The pattern for picture is Landscapes_XXX_h_Y.jpg
where
XXX is number from 1 to 185 and Y is quality version from A to E

I wanna select each image name with different quality.

The output should be

```
+-----+---------+------------------------+
| ID  | ID_TEST | FILE_PATH              |
+-----+---------+------------------------+
| 575 |       3 | Landscapes_001_h_A.jpg |
| 576 |       3 | Landscapes_002_h_E.jpg |
| 577 |       3 | Landscapes_003_h_C.jpg |
| 578 |       3 | Landscapes_004_h_B.jpg |
| 579 |       3 | Landscapes_005_h_D.jpg |
| 580 |       3 | Landscapes_006_h_A.jpg |
| 581 |       3 | Landscapes_007_h_E.jpg |
| 582 |       3 | Landscapes_008_h_C.jpg |
| 583 |       3 | Landscapes_009_h_B.jpg |
| 584 |       3 | Landscapes_010_h_E.jpg |
+-----+---------+------------------------+
```

but of course for 185 elements.
I'm using  5.5.60-MariaDB.
How to write SELECT statement? Using REGEXP?

Comment: how do you choose quality? randomly? what's the logic behind choosing quality

Comment: what you ask depends on your DBMS and version(please tag DBMS and its version).

Comment: It should be randomly. I need Select only one version not 5.

Comment: I would just create columns for XXX and Y and be done with it.

Select id, id_test, file_path from table order by xxx;

Comment: @Steve How to extract XXX number and Y version from each file using sql?

Comment: If the structure of the file_name is constant, length etc and always has landscapes then you could just use substring. 

Insert into table (xxx, y) values (select substring(xxx, 12, 3) as xxx, substring(xxx, 18,1);

If the structure is not the same, ie you can have landscap_... and sky_... then you would need to add locate_in_string to find where the part of the field you want start. something like substring(xxx, locate_in_string(xxx, '_')+1, 3) as xxx and probably something a little more complicated for the finding y

Locate_in_string is a db2 thing, oracle and sqlserver are different.

Comment: What is an "image"?  You say "I wanna select each image name with different quality" but "image" is not defined.

Comment: I want to select FILE_PATH, you have the following output below. I have 925 records in db, 185 file names and each has 5 different quality from A to E. How to select only 185 records but the quality factor will change randomly.

Comment: What is "image name"?  Just "Landscape"?  Or "Landscape_001"?  Or something else?

Comment: Landscape_XXX_Y.jpg where  XXX is number and Y is quality